# Get Error after deploying symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony

After deploying the recipe environment, I have the error in the log:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught Exception PHP InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template" "". /var/www/msc-extranet/recette/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line at 128 { "exception": "[object] (InvalidArgumentException (code: 0): Unable to find template \ "\" at /var/www/msc-extranet/recette/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php:128, Twig_Error_Loader (code: 0). Unable to find template \ ". \" at /var/www/msc-extranet/recette/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php:91, InvalidArgumentException (code: 0): Unable to find template \ "\". \ ". An empty file name is not valid to be Located \" at / var / www / msc-extranet / recipe / app / cache / prod / classes.php: 803 InvalidArgumentException (code: 0). An empty file name is not valid to be site location is /var/www/msc-extranet/recette/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1622) "} []

someone help me , thx a lot

Comment: One of your controllers is passing wrong template name to render function.

Comment: thx for your response  but i'm using return array and not $this->render in all of my controllers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a similar issue few time ago.

Please, check your controller, if you are using Template annotation. In this case, make sure to use default one as

```
@Template()
```

And not as

```
@Template("")
```

Comment: thank u, i use template annotation like @Template("") . When i use the default one , i don't enter into my local application.

Comment: Using `@Template("")` is what is causing error. You need to use `@Template()`. If you don't enter in, can you post some code please?

Comment: So please, mark this question as solved, would be better :)